# What is the solution for this error? bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: linux, ros

When I run this to update description tag:

```
5  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>
```

The error shows:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

I am beginner on linux.

Comment: can you be more detailed and specific? what are you trying to do with what bash command?

Comment: i want to update package.xml file with using                                                5   <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>                             http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage   7.1.1 description tag

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open `package.xml` up in a text editor and then make that change. You can't just type:

```
5   <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>
```

And expect the computer has any idea what you want to do.

On the command line you can use `vi`, `vim`, `nano`, or whatever text editor is available in your system to open the file up and make the changes.

If `nano` is available probably best to use that if your a new to the whole command line thing. It works like you would expect it to. You can use:

```
nano package.xml
```

To open the file, the commands to work the file editor in `nano` are listed at the bottom of the screen.

Lastly that `5` is just part of that websites line numbering for the code. Chances are your `<description>` tag is on line 5 of the `package.xml` file. Don't put `5` in the file itself otherwise your xml will be corrupted and nothing that uses that file will work.